# What is the meaning of "to shift gears from fight to flight"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms

> By 5:45 p.m it was clear that even containing the fire was off the table. Realizing it was time to shift gears fight to flight, Dodge immediately turned the crew around to run back up the slope.

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?  Do you know what "shift gears" means?  Do you understand what "fight" and "flight" mean?

Comment: "Off the table" is a metaphor, as is "shift gears". The fire crew shifts from "forwards" to "reverse".

Comment: Note that it is **flight** as in **flee**, not **flight** as in **fly**.

Comment: Closure seems unreasonable. It's a question about the meaning of an idiom, i.e., they are not literally shifting gears.

Comment: you said that ,it is metaphors.and means: reverse.ok???

Comment: To spell it out: "[off the table](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+the+table)" means "no longer an option". To "[shift gears](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shift+gears)" means to "change what one is doing". The alternatives "[fight or flight](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fight+or+flight)" are an idiom contrasting two reactions to a situation. So the whole thing means "The fire crew realised that the fire had become too dangerous to stop, so they ran to save their lives."